# How to view the latest YouTube videos for a particular tag

Tags: youtube

When you upload a video to YouTube, you can "tag" it with whatever you want.

I don't see those tags listed anywhere, although if you view source for a particular video, the tags are present in the video embed code.

However, what I would like to do is view videos for a particular tag. Then we can ask our constituency to post videos and "tag" them with, e.g,. #our-unique-tag. If we can then view a list of videos that have that tag, newest to oldest, we'll pick out interesting videos and re-post them to our channel.

Is this possible? Is there a better alternative, aside from asking customers to upload their video to YouTube and then manually notify us? That would work, but we'd prefer if we could be automatically notified, or at least have the videos show up in a list automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since you asked, but YouTube did implement hashtags since which work pretty much exactly like you want them to work.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6390658